# Apache mod_rewrite - remove extension/add trailing slash/preserve directory structure

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I am currently using the following .htaccess file to remove the .php extension from my files and add a trailing slash to all URLs:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This is working great, however, when I have a php file in a directory, and I want to serve that file from a directory I get a 404 error. Is there a way to do this with 1 .htaccess file in the root. I really don't want to remember to put a .htaccess file in each directory.

Right now

```
www.myexample.com/information/
```

Serves `/information.php`. Great! However

```
www.myexample.com/categories/category-1/
```

this throws a 404 even though the file `/categories/category-1.php` does exist. I would like to modify my .htaccess file so this serves `/categories/category-1.php`.

Answer (score 2):

The regex pattern for first rewrite rule is the reason: `^([^/]+)/$` means *any character EXCEPT slash `/`*. Therefore it rejects anything that is located in sub folder.

You should use `^(.+)/$` pattern instead -- this will work for `/information/` as well as `/categories/category-1/` as well as `/categories/category-1/hello-kitten/`.

**P.S.** I would also add the `L` flag to stop matching further rules:

```
# add .php file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: @Henry Wrinkler What error is that? Please check Apache's error log for details.

Comment: Ok, this works with one issue.  If I navigate to www.example.com/categories/category-1  It works. However, if I navigate to www.example.com/categories/category-1/ It throws a 500 error. I would be ok with this and just stop using the trailing slash rule, however, is there a way to get this to throw a proper 404 error instead of a 500 error?

Comment: @Henry Sorry .. I typed the answer .. then I could not access my Apache box (for some reason) to verify the code in real action, so I reverted it back. But now it is confirmed (see my updated rule): use this pattern `^(.*[^/])/?$` instead of `^(.+)$`. This will work for both with and without trailing slash. If you want to ONLY work WITH slash, then remove `?` from the pattern.

Comment: @Henry Wrinkler So .. did this worked for you?